# How to only display open ports

Tags: nmap, ports

I'm very new to Nmap. I'm using Nmap to find open ports of an IP by this command:

```
nmap -v -Pn -p 1-100 "$ip" -oG -
```

Here is the output:

```
Host: IP

Ports:
6/closed/tcp/unknown
19/closed/tcp/chargen
20/closed/tcp/ftp-data
21/open/tcp/ftp
22/closed/tcp/ssh
23/closed/tcp/telnet
25/open/tcp/smtp
32/closed/tcp/unknown
50/closed/tcp/re-mail-ck
53/closed/tcp/domain
56/closed/tcp/xns-auth
62/closed/tcp/acas
68/closed/tcp/dhcpc
72/closed/tcp/netrjs-2
76/closed/tcp/deos
80/open/tcp//http
100/closed/tcp//newacct

Ignored State: filtered (83)
```

As you see there are some closed ports in the result too. How can I change my command so that only open ports are displayed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nmap has the option `--open`, which will filter out all the other potential states. If you are scanning under Linux, you could also use grep to achieve a very similar result.

Here is what the man pages have to say about it:

> --open (Show only open (or possibly open) ports)
>
> Sometimes you only care about ports you can actually connect to (open
>   ones), and don't want results cluttered with closed, filtered, and
>   closed|filtered ports. Output customization is normally done after the
>   scan using tools such as grep, awk, and Perl, but this feature was
>   added due to overwhelming requests. Specify --open to only see hosts
>   with at least one open, open|filtered, or unfiltered port, and only
>   see ports in those states. These three states are treated just as they
>   normally are, which means that open|filtered and unfiltered may be
>   condensed into counts if there are an overwhelming number of them.

Comment: How should I apply --open to my command? Like this: `nmap -v -Pn -p 1-100 --open "$ip" -oG -` ?

Comment: @Pablo - Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: Yes, I tried it several times, it seems to work. I wanted to be sure that I'm using the correct command.

Comment: open|filtered ports still showing. If you try UDP all ports scan, nmap showed all open|filtered ports. I use it with grep to hang it.